# Error when creating a network-like figure a truss in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot

I would like to create a truss model, using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

elementsmat=[[1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3], [3, 3, 4], [4, 4, 5], [5, 5, 1], [6, 1, 4], [7, 2, 4], [8, 4, 6], [9, 6, 5]]
nodesmat= [[1.0, 0.0, 1.2], [2.0, -1.5, 1.2], [3.0, -1.5, 0.0], [4.0, 0.0, 0.0], [5.0, 1.5, 1.2], [6.0, 1.5, 0.0]]


bars=[]
for i in range(len(elementsmat)):
    bars.append(elementsmat[i][1:])
print(bars)

def image(nodes, c, lt, lw, lg):
    nodes_xy=[]
    for j in range(len(nodes)):
        nodes_xy.append(nodes[j][1:])
    print(nodes_xy)
    for i in range(len(bars)):
        xi, xf = nodes_xy[bars[i][0]][0], nodes_xy[bars[i][1]][0] 
        yi, yf = nodes_xy[bars[i][0]][1], nodes_xy[bars[i][1]][1]
        line, = plt.plot([xi,xf],[yi,yf], color=c, linestyle=lt, linewidth=lw)
    line.set_label=lg
    plt.legend(prop={'size':8})
    
image(nodesmat, 'gray', '--', 1, 'not deformed')
```

Where the list `elementsmat` works like this: element one is composed of node 1 and node 2. The other dataset, `nodesmat`, gives the nodes followed by their coordinates in the 2D plane. I would like to have something like this:

[image]

But I am getting the following image and error:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: There are 6 indices in that line. First you must find out which of them is meant by the error message. Either split the line into multiple statements or use a debugger.

Comment: For a start, use `for bar in bars` instead of `for i in range(len(bars))`, and similarly for other for loops. It's generally better and will make finding index errors simpler.

Comment: Python counts from zero, you count fom one (in both `*mat`).